# Unable to use lwc:dynamic directive in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lwc-dom, lwc-oss

[image: Error When using lwc:dynamic directive]

How do I enable the lwc:dynamic directive or is it tied to certain release of Salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

The [lwc:dynamic](https://rfcs.lwc.dev/rfcs/lwc/0110-dynamic-components) directive is not currently enabled on Salesforce platform. The feature might be enabled based on feedback from internal Salesforce developers. There is currently no timeline for public enablement.